# Junit test for @RequestPart

Tags: spring-boot

Here I want to write a test for following controller method for a spring-boot application, on executing method of the test class I'm getting an error Bad Request: Required request part 'formData' is not present, I've tried finding a solution for testing an object having 'RequestPart' annotation but no luck

```
//method needs to be tested
@PostMapping("/user")
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> createUser(@RequestPart(value = "files", required= false) MultipartFile[] files,
@RequestPart("formData") UserDTO userDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
    userService.save(userDTO, files);
}

// Inside testclass
@BeforeEach
public void initTest()
{
    user = createEntity(em);// inside this method I've set all the properties of user object
}

public void createUser() throws Exception {
    UserDTO userDTO = userMapper.toDto(user);
    mockMvc
        .perform(post("/api/user")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(userDTO)))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a multipart request using `MockMultipartFile` with something like this:

```
    MockMultipartFile api = new MockMultipartFile (
        "file",
        "foo.zip",
        "application/zip", "foo".bytes)
```

and then use it like this:

```
    mvc.perform (
        multipart ('/api/foo')
            .file (api))
       .andExpect(...)
```

This is for a file upload (groovy code), so you have to adjust it a little bit.

Comment: thanks for this but I also saw WebConfig class which has MultipartResolver bean annotation on adding that class, I'm getting an error as error creating multipartResolver Bean in classpath Webconfig.class nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver]: Factory method 'multipartResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory                        Can you please suggest something ?

Comment: I can find two resolvers: CommonsMultipartResolver & StandardServletMultipartResolver. First one is using apache-commons. Looks like my code is using the second one. I don't have anything in WebConfig for this and i don't have commons.fileupload in my classpath.